# What's the purpose of payment.xml

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I'm curious about the purpose of a payment.xml and the controls it provides for a specific payment method. Also, I have seen different tags in one of the payment.xml from the vendor.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
    <credit_cards>
        <type id="SM" order="60">
            <label>Switch/Maestro</label>
        </type>
        <type id="SO" order="61">
            <label>Solo</label>
        </type>
    </credit_cards>
    <groups>
        <group id="paypal">
            <label>PayPal</label>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <methods>
        <method name="paypal_direct">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
        <method name="paypal_billing_agreement">
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
        </method>
    </methods>
</payment>
```

I would appreciate your thoughts on this. Thanks